# How to exclude total sessions when comparing segments in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

In previous versions of Google Analytics it was possible to uncheck total sessions when comparing segments so that only the checked segments would be graphed.

But now I can't figure out how to quickly exclude total sessions. And I'm left with a graph that looks like this:

[image]

Is it still possible to exclude total ("Sessions" in the graph above)?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Segments.

Near the top of the report page, you should see a box with a circle, and next to it the words "All Sessions." That's the default segment.

To the right of that box is the "Add Segment" box. Click it. Then click the New Segment button. In the case of Countries, you'll have to create an Advanced Segment using Conditions. See the picture below. Add a name to the Segment like "Countries - USA".

Repeat this for each country you want to graph.

After you do this, ensure all the Segments you added are listed in the top, and that the "All Sessions" segment is not listed.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This works, but it's time consuming and allows one to only compare 4 segments (countries) at once. But it does work.

Answer (score 3):

Motion Charts might save you a few steps over messing with segments.

1. From the screen you want to analyze, click the Motion Charts icon (three circles, next to the line chart)
2. Select the line graph tab
3. Check the boxes of the rows you want to display
4. Click the wrench icon to increase the opacity of the other items
5. Select your metric on the left side of chart

This tutorial will be more helpful with its included screenshots: http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2014/07/16/dynamic-data-viz-plot-rows-google-analytics/